# My Navbar won't align Horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am currently using Bootstrap 3 to create a website for my first client, but I can't get the navbar to align properly. It stops displaying inline when I hit the col-sm breakpoint. I have looked up many other articles and have applied many different CSS properties but to no avail. At this point, I think there could be a bug in my code, but I don't know for sure. This is my first real project, so I am technically a newbie ( excuse my terrible code :P ). Please let me know if there is anything I am missing. Here is a screenshot and my code.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.html">Spa&bull;ology</a>
        </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->
        <!--NAV LINKS-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <!--LINKS-->
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <!--DROPDOWN LINKS-->
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="waxingandsugaring.html">Waxing &amp; Sugaring</a></li>
                        <li><a href="manisandpedis.html">Manis &amp; Pedis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="spraytanning.html">Spray Tanning</a></li>
                        <li><a href="massages.html">Massages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="lashes.html">Lash Extensions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="facialsandpeels.html">Facials &amp; Peels</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- /.dropdwon-menu -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.secure-booker.com/spaology/ShopOnline/GiftCertificate.aspx" target="_blank">Gift Certificates</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.secure-booker.com/spaology/MakeAppointment/" target="_blank">Book Online</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Here are some of the CSS properties I have tried. I have used different combinations of these properties with no avail.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
float:left;    
} 

.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
display:inline;    
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
display:block;
float:left;
vertical-align: top  
}
```

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear the first time. I never used the float property more than once per edit. I used both of them in separate instances, but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: The main issue I am having is that .navbar-brand adds a line break once I hit the col-sm breakpoint and the navbar is no longer inline. It separates into two lines, thus no longer inline. I hope this helps clear up the question I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the all of the relevant CSS, it's hard to give specific advice. However, Bootstrap navbar menus are coded to switch to hidden at the breakpoint you indicate, and the menu items themselves stack vertically.

You can see for yourself here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

In order to have your menu stay visible and the items (the `<li>` elements) remain inline, you need to adjust or otherwise override the CSS for that breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added a screenshot of the issue I am having. Maybe this will help better explain my issue.

Comment: I see - the menu itself is bumping down. This is usually the result of there simply being no space to contain both elements (the logo and menu) side-by-side. The logo and elements are a static width, so as the screen narrows, there is less room for them. This is precisely why mobile menus tend to be hidden. 

There are several ways to address this. One, reduce the size (width) of the elements so they can co-exist inline. Two, widen the container so there is more room. Three, adopt a mobile-style hidden menu. Four, allow the elements to exist one above the other, perhaps centering them.

Comment: Great suggestions. If its not too much to ask, would you be able to post an example of the CSS I could use? I apologize if I am asking for too much, I just am really new to this and would like to approach this the right way, rather than blindly. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen? Also, I can't really suggest anything useful without the CSS involved, because it would appear that you're not relying solely on Bootstrap. Try adding the relevant CSS to your code in your question and make it a runnable snippet: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I actually took your advice and reduced the width of the elements. With a little fiddling around, i eventually got it all to line up properly across all breakpoints. Thank you very much for your suggestions!!!

Comment: Great to hear! Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just by looking at your css you have defined display and float 2 times. remove the duplicate entries and modify as needed

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
display:inline;
position:relative;
display:block;
float:left;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

try this https://jsfiddle.net/4k1yoctf/2/

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added a screenshot of the issue I am having. Maybe this will help better explain my issue.

Comment: @umaldo7 are you talking about the name floating to top?

Comment: That is correct. It seems as if the navbar-brand adds a line break once I hit the col-sm breakpoint, thus making the navbar not-inline. The navbar remains inline for MD & LG breakpoints, and collapses once I hit the XS breakpoint. I am only having the issue once I hit the SM breakpoint. I know this is due to the fact that there is little space left for the two sections. Is there some kind of CSS trick/hack that I am missing?

Comment: @umaldo7 I updated answer. just note that the setting for the logo name is navbar branding class

Comment: Thanks for the link. Based on your answer, the only alternative I have is to collapse the navbar once I hit the SM breakpoint. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @umaldo7 I am not sure exactly what you need with the code provided it works fine in bootstrap.. we need to see if  your nav is in a header or div.. or what you non boostrap css looks like you have something wrong some where but what you have provided is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input and advice. You all deserve medals! I fixed this issue by reducing the size (width) of the elements of the navbar. With some pixel manipulation, I was able to fit all the navbar items in one line. Here is an example of the CSS I used to fix the issue. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
.navbar .navbar-header > a {
font-size: 1.4em;
width: 40px;
padding-left: 0px;
```

}